# find_by_slug(params[:id]) always return null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm just using Ruby on Rails 3.1, and I want use mongoid and mongoid_slug gem to make my url readable. There is my problem:
In my photo mode iput this code: "include Mongoid::Document", "include Mongoid::Slug" and 
"slug :title" ( title is one of photo's attributes)
And in my controller, I call thí one in my action:
"@photo = Photo.find_by_slug(params[:id])" but this code always return a null value!!
Please, help me!

Comment: I think that my routes is ok! because if i use the old code: "@photo = Photo.find(params[:id]) it's still work!

Comment: No! I mean that I want to have a readable link such as /photo/a-cockroach instead of /photo/sadfasf12312. When i call find(params[:id]) in my controller, the url is /photo/_id!! Actually, i don't want the _id showed in andress, I just wanna photo.title (which is slug) in the address!
Sorry because i'm pretty new in ror T__T!!

Comment: Here is my route: match '/artwork/:id' => "pages#artwork", :as => "artwork". I call: Photo.find(params[:id]) in my artwork action, and i don't think that there is a problem here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found my own answer but thanks you anyway! it always return null value because the model doesn't load the slug (that means every object of the model doesn't have "slug:title"). Therefore, I have to init slug to my model. I write in my db.rake file the following code and run rake db:init_slug. This my init_slug task: "photo.all.each do |p| p.send(:generate_slug!) p.save!" Then restart the server one more time and the code doesn't return null value anymore